# How to remove rows with NaNs in several specific columns

Tags: matlab

I put all my data in one huge table and now struggling trying to work with it. I need to remove rows that have NaNs in several specific columns. Additionally, the table is inside of an array. Here is a simplified version:

```
Col1 = [ 1;   1;   1;  NaN];
Col2 = [ 1;   1;  NaN; NaN];
Col3 = [NaN; NaN; NaN;  1 ];
Col4 = [ 1;   1;  NaN; NaN];
Rows = {'Row1'; 'Row2'; 'Row3'; 'Row4'};
T = table(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, 'RowNames', Rows)   %this is the table

data(1).tables = T         %this is the array that contains the table
```

The table looks like this:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
        ____    ____    ____    ____

Row1      1       1     NaN       1 
Row2      1       1     NaN       1 
Row3      1     NaN     NaN     NaN 
Row4    NaN     NaN       1     NaN
```

I need to remove all rows that have all NaNs in column 2 to 4. So in this example Row3 should be removed and the output would be like this:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
        ____    ____    ____    ____

Row1      1       1     NaN       1 
Row2      1       1     NaN       1 
Row4    NaN     NaN       1     NaN
```

In the real table there are many columns so I would need to remove rows with NaNs in columns, say, 130 to 160. So listing them with commas would be undesirable. But all of the columns that need to be checked for NaNs are adjacent so ideally it should specify a range of columns, like: `data(1).tables2 = data(1).tables(~isnan(data(1).tables(:,2:4), :))`, which doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can get it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the following one-line solution:

```
T(all(isnan(T{:,2:4}),2),:) = []
```

That gives the delicious result:

```
T = 

            Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
            ____    ____    ____    ____

    Row1      1       1     NaN       1 
    Row2      1       1     NaN       1 
    Row4    NaN     NaN       1     NaN
```

Comment: It's identical to my logical indexing solution, but +1 anyway since you posted it while I was still editing mine... =) I'll keep my answer there since it solves it similar to the way OP tried (after the `data(1).tables` line.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this the following way:

```
row_idx = find(all(isnan(data(1).tables{:,2:3}),2))
data(1).tables(row_idx,:) = [];
```

Now you have:

```
data(1).tables
ans = 
            Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
            ____    ____    ____    ____

    Row1      1       1     NaN       1 
    Row2      1       1     NaN       1 
    Row4    NaN     NaN       1     NaN
```

You can also do this using only logical indexing, but in my opinion it's often OK to use find first to retrieve the indices. But note: You should use logical indexing if your tables are very large, and/or if speed is important.

With logical indexing:

```
data(1).tables(all(isnan(data(1).tables{:,2:3}),2),:) = [];
```

**Breakdown:**

Create a matrix with ones where there are NaNs in the 2. and 3. columns.

```
isnan(data(1).tables{:,2:3})
```

Check if both values are equal to 1. Note the last `2`. Without this, `all` will look through rows instead of columns.

```
all(isnan(data(1).tables{:,2:3}),2)
```

Find the indices of the NaN-rows

```
find(all(isnan(data(1).tables{:,2:3}),2))
```

And finally, remove those rows from the table:

```
data(1).tables(row_idx,:) = [];
```